# Python - Add .gzip attachment to email

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I use my Script there always comes this error:

```py
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'/folder/my/20200114-013815/backup.sql.gz'"
```

Why can't the file be found? It's on the Path.
Or do I have to add a gzip encoding or whatever to  `attachment.add_header`? Don't know what's wrong, it's the first time I tried to add an attachment in python.

Thanks

```py
DB_HOST = 'XXXXXXX' 
DB_USER = 'XXXXXXX'
DB_USER_PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXX'
DB_NAME = 'XXXXXXX'
BACKUP_PATH = '/folder/my'

DATETIME = time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
TODAYBACKUPPATH = BACKUP_PATH + '/' + DATETIME

try:
    os.stat(TODAYBACKUPPATH)
except:
    os.mkdir(TODAYBACKUPPATH)


if os.path.exists(DB_NAME):
    file1 = open(DB_NAME)
    multi = 1
else:
    multi = 0

if multi:
    in_file = open(DB_NAME,"r")
    flength = len(in_file.readlines())
    in_file.close()
    p = 1
    dbfile = open(DB_NAME,"r")

    while p <= flength:
        db = dbfile.readline()   
        db = db[:-1]         
        dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
        os.system(dumpcmd)
        gzipcmd = "gzip " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
        os.system(gzipcmd)
        p = p + 1
    dbfile.close()
else:
    db = DB_NAME
    dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
    os.system(dumpcmd)
    gzipcmd = "gzip " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + db + ".sql"
    os.system(gzipcmd)


    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    message = "Test" 

    password = "XXXXXXXX"
    msg['From'] = "XXXXXXXX"
    msg['To'] = "XXXXXXXX"
    msg['Subject'] = "Test"

    filename = "'" + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/backup.sql.gz'"

    f = file(filename)

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',   filename=filename)           
    msg.attach(attachment)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('XXXXXXXX: 587')

    server.starttls()

    server.login(msg['From'], password)

    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your string concatenation, here:

```
filename = "'" + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/backup.sql.gz'"
```

You need to remove the single quotes that you're adding - why are you adding them?
Change it to this:

```
filename = TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/backup.sql.gz"
```

Comment: Oh yes that works, but now in the email is the attachment name like: `/folder/my/20200114-013815/backup.sql.gz` and if i download it its not an `gzip file`, if i open it the file within is not an sql file, instead an folder with name `€ìZYsã8’~Þú_Ø'WÏØ5__ððFG´_ê¾EÙ’^Ü__‰–DJ$uþúM@’­Ãe»T_]_±íQõ_d___‘___äÝ_ªnÚÍ__r_Ó_ÂÒ7¬ ”õã$ò_¢ùâ»ª_ùV6}‹¼0BŽ;ð­ànâ_‹õÝ0X ¯kMyRèo_îîà‡__aœÜ£Ih[“_` and 20 folder in it.

Comment: Sorry its an gzip file, but in this file its not an sql file, its an folder.

Comment: Hmm, I think you'll have to take a look and think about what it is then that this line of code does: `attachment = MIMEText(f.read())`.

Comment: Oh  i have replaced `MIMEText` with `MIMEApplication` and works now:) Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the absolute path here ? if not, try using it.

Comment: Yes the path is correct, if i print it out and check my folder the files was created or what you mean?

Comment: Absolute path means path from the root, not from the current directory.
Also, its better to use os.path.join() to merge the paths.

Comment: Yes i use absolute path. See the other answer below from "ev350", this works but inside is now not an sql file.